# PHP Codeigniter and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hello i totally new in codeigniter and jquery.below is my problem by default button is "Simpan" and after click "Simpan" that button it will change to "Ubah" and some field disabled.Problem is i cannot click back button "Ubah" and back to normal..anyone can help?

thanks you

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#sama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").click(function(){
           $("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").hide(1000);
           $("#statussama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").show(1000);
           $("#statustidaksama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").hide(1000);
         });
         $("#tidak<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").click(function(){
            $("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").show(1000);
            $("#statustidaksama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").show(1000);
            $("#statussama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").hide(1000);  
         });
         $("#simpan<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").click(function(){
            $("#simpan<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").text("Ubah");
            $("tr.tr_<?php echo $row['br_loc']; ?>").addClass("disable_test");
            $("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#sama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#tidak<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").prop('disabled', true);
         });
        });
        </script>
          <tr class="tr_<?php echo $row['br_loc']; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['br_loc']; ?></td>
            <td style="width:300px;"><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
            <td>RM <?php echo $row['sum']; ?>  <input id="test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" type="text" class="test" style="width:70px; display:none;"></td>
            <td><span id ="statussama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" class="label label-success">sama</span><span id ="statustidaksama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" style="display:none;" class="label label-warning">Tidak Sama</span></td> 
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="sama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button> 
                <button type="button" id="tidak<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button> 
            </td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" id="simpan<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" >Simpan</a></td>
          </tr>
         <?php
                $no++;
            }
         ?>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You are setting the property disabled to true. That means you can no longer use the element. The elements are disabled.

Comment: Ubah mean EDIT,that one i not disable so that when i click it back to normal.Normal is "Simpan" mean "SAVE"..thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't write js in loop. You should write function js.

```
<tr class="tr_<?php echo $row['br_loc']; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['br_loc']; ?></td>
        <td style="width:300px;"><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
        <td>RM <?php echo $row['sum']; ?>  <input id="test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" type="text" class="test" style="width:70px; display:none;"></td>
        <td><span id ="statussama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" class="label label-success">sama</span><span id ="statustidaksama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" style="display:none;" class="label label-warning">Tidak Sama</span></td> 
        <td>
            <button type="button" id="sama<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button> 
            <button type="button" id="tidak<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button> 
        </td>
        <td>
             <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeStatus($(this))" id="simpan<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" >Simpan</a>
             <input type="hidden" value="0" class="hd_status" />
        </td>
      </tr>
     <?php
            $no++;
        }
     ?>
```

And function js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeStatus(el) {
if(el.next().val() == 0) {
    //action
    el.next().val(1);
}
else {
    //action
    el.next().val(0);
}
}
</script>
```